# How to configure the fstab and grub file after restoring Ubuntu with a clonezilla image

Tags: grub2, backup, fstab, restore, clonezilla

I have restored my Ubuntu partition into a new disk with clonezilla. During the restoring, there is a disclaimer that suggest the editing of the fstab and grub file. Unfortunately I have no idea on how to configure them. Any help is very appreciated! Please keep it simple as I am a beginner.

Comment: Don't worry it will work just fine!
Those configuration changes might be necessary if you are restoring your files on different  computers - like cloning your machine on a classroom set   --  See Clone(Zilla)  for cloning PC's fast

Comment: The Ubuntu I restored into a new disk does not boot tho :/

Comment: Did you take the image of the whole disk, or only of your Ubuntu partition?
It seems that you are missing the boot sector on your new disk!

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a partial answer, I will provide the solution I have found. I figured that I messed up in creating the image as I did not include the boot partition. What I finally did was to back up my /home partition through `rsync`;  wipe out all Partitions; Fresh install Ubuntu; `rsync` back my /home partition and fix any errors (probably related to the `.xAuthority` file)  through Live repair Ubuntu solution keeping the data restored. I didn't backup a whole image of my OS but now since I have created a dedicated partition for my /home sector I'll be fine at least for the majority of the personal files I keep and plug-ins installed.